# Extracting the text from a textview

Tags: android, string, textview

Hi guys I need help on a rather trivial problem that I can't solve, then I'm writing an app for android with android studio, what the app should do is read the contents of the TextView, text-only format without numbers or anything , and based on the content of the TextView should change image or text, I can not I tried to write this code but it does not work, could you please tell me where I am wrong and write me some code, thanks.

```
    public class CashBackPage extends AppCompatActivity {

        public FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        public AdView adViewTop, adViewBot;

        TextView mLogout;
        TextView mTxtPhone;
        TextView mPhone;
        TextView mReadCash;
        TextView mVersionApp;
        TextView mCodeRappCash;
        TextView mGeneralTextCash, mSendRequestText;
        ImageButton mSendRequest, mCancel;
        LinearLayout mbannerTop, mbannerBot;
        FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cash_back_page);
            mLogout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logoutbutn);
            mTxtPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextPhone);
            mPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumberPhTxt);
            mReadCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ReadCashBack);
            mVersionApp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.VersionApp);
            mSendRequest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.SendRequestBtn);
            mCancel = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.CancelBtn);
            mCodeRappCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CodeDiscountCash);
            mGeneralTextCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textgeneralacash);
            mSendRequestText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textsendrequest);

            mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        initFirebase();

        //Set Orientation Portrait
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        getnumberprefs();

        if (!isEmpty (String.valueOf(mCodeRappCash))){
            String textgen = mCodeRappCash.getText().toString().trim();
            if (textgen.equals("Request code sent...")){

                mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{

                mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Read to the database CashBack
        DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
        myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("CashBack").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String cashback = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mReadCash.setText(cashback);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        // Read to the database Version App
        myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("Version App").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String versionapp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mVersionApp.setText(versionapp);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        // Read to the database Code Cash Back
        myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("RappCash Code").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String coderappcash = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mCodeRappCash.setText(coderappcash);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void logoutclick(View view) {
        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(30);
        mAuth.signOut();
        updateUI();
    }

    private void initFirebase() {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        FirebaseUser currentuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentuser == null){
            Intent intTologin = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intTologin);
        }
    }

    private void getnumberprefs() {
        SharedPreferences numb = getSharedPreferences(Register.NUMB, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String numberphn = numb.getString(Register.KEY_NUMB,null);
        mPhone.setText(numberphn);
    }

    public void sendrequest(View view) {
        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(30);
        DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
        myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("RappCash Code").setValue("Request code sent...");
    }

    public void cancelrequest(View view) {
        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(30);
        new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
                myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("RappCash Code").setValue("Request code canceled...");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
                myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("RappCash Code").setValue("#RappCashCode");
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private boolean isEmpty (String mCoins) {
        return mCoins.contentEquals("#RappCashCode");
    }
}
```

so only if the text is the same as "Request code sent ..." it changes image or text contained in another textview, I entered this code in both OnStart and OnCreate but in both cases it doesn't work.

I state that the TextView reads the content of a line of a real time database firebase and that it returns in the app what is written on the database

Comment: I believe the problem arises when I go to read the values on the realtime database, which are not in text format

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Okay, relating to your code the problem is simple. TextView is checked for text, before is set.

You are firstly calling check on onCreate():

```
if (!isEmpty (String.valueOf(mCodeRappCash))){
        String textgen = mCodeRappCash.getText().toString().trim();
        if (textgen.equals("Request code sent...")){

            mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{

            mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

And then you are calling on onStart():

```
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String coderappcash = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mCodeRappCash.setText(coderappcash);
        }
```

You have to get reference to database earlier, and set your TextView before check. So for example:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cash_back_page);
    mLogout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logoutbutn);
    mTxtPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextPhone);
    mPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumberPhTxt);
    mReadCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ReadCashBack);
    mVersionApp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.VersionApp);
    mSendRequest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.SendRequestBtn);
    mCancel = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.CancelBtn);
    mCodeRappCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CodeDiscountCash);
    mGeneralTextCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textgeneralacash);
    mSendRequestText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textsendrequest);

    mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    initFirebase();

    //Set Orientation Portrait
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    getnumberprefs();

    //You have to set mCodeRappCash value before this check!!!
    // Read to the database Code Cash Back
    DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();

    myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("RappCash Code").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String coderappcash = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mCodeRappCash.setText(coderappcash);
        }

    if (!isEmpty (String.valueOf(mCodeRappCash))){
        String textgen = mCodeRappCash.getText().toString().trim();
        if (textgen.equals("Request code sent...")){

            mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{

            mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work because it can't read the contents of the TextView

Comment: Pardon me, I though that MCodeRappCash is EditText field.

Did you tried to log textgen string after getting text from textview? Does it show anything?

Comment: shows the second definition and not the first, so everything below works }else{

Comment: So, first statement doesn't work? I mean if text is exactly "Request code sent..." nothing happens? Or it goes straight to else statement?

Comment: go directly to the declaration else statement

Comment: I did a test and the TextView mCodeRappCash it is empty there is no text in it

Comment: Check if initialization is done properly. For example if you didn't misspelled id name (it's very common mistake).

Maybe you are changing reference to that TextView in the runtime? It's hard to tell without whole code, or just snippets regarding this TextView.

Comment: I've posted all the code so I can quickly see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

I solved and found this banal problem, thanks to the same to all those who answered, under the portion of code solved.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Read to the database CashBack
        DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
        myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("CashBack").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String cashback = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mReadCash.setText(cashback);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        // Read to the database Version App
        myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("Version App").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String versionapp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mVersionApp.setText(versionapp);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        // Read to the database Code Cash Back
        myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("RappCash Code").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String coderappcash = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mCodeRappCash.setText(coderappcash);

                assert coderappcash != null;
                if (!isEmpty (coderappcash)){
                    if (coderappcash.equals("Request code sent...")){
                        mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else{
                        mSendRequestText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mGeneralTextCash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

the information was contained in (coderappcash)